# How can I use a seed inside a loop to get the same random samples everytime the code is ran?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, random, seed

I want to generate data using random numbers and then generate random samples with replacement using the generated data. The problem is that using `random.seed(10)` only fixes the initial random numbers for the generated data but it does not fix the random samples generated inside the loop, everytime I run the code I get the same generated data but different random samples and I would like to get the same random samples in order to get reproducible results. The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(10)

data = list(np.random.binomial(size = 215 , n=1, p= 0.3))

sample_mean = []

for i in range(1000):

    sample = random.choices(data, k=215)
    mean = np.mean(sample)
    sample_mean.append(mean)

print(np.mean(sample_mean))
```

`np.mean(sample_mean)` should retrieve the same value every time the code is ran but it does not happen.

I tried typing random.seed(i) inside the loop but it didn't work.

Comment: please fix you code indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing the seed for `np.random` doesn't fix the seed for `random`...
So adding a simple line for fixing *both* seeds will give you reproducible results:

```
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(10)
random.seed(10)

data = list(np.random.binomial(size=215, n=1, p=0.3))

sample_mean = []

for i in range(1000):
    sample = random.choices(data, k=215)
    mean = np.mean(sample)
    sample_mean.append(mean)

print(np.mean(sample_mean))
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `np.random.choices` instead of `random.choices`.

Answer (score 3):

your `random.choices(data, k=215)` is from python builtin `random` library which has a different seed than the one inside `numpy.random`, so seeding numpy isn't enough.

the correct solution here is to use numpy `np.random.choice` here as you are already using numpy.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)

data = np.random.binomial(size=215, n=1, p=0.3)

sample_mean = []

for i in range(1000):
    sample = np.random.choice(data,size=215)
    mean = np.mean(sample)
    sample_mean.append(mean)


print(np.mean(sample_mean))
```

ps: calling `list` on `data` is not necessary, and will slow your code down.